# Travelling to Morocco with two passports (one is Moroccan), which one to use?

Tags: visas, uk, morocco, kenyan-citizens

I have a Kenyan passport and a Moroccan passport, and I am a student studying in the UK. The Kenyan passport is the only passport out of the two listed that has the British student visa. If I want to travel to Morocco, which passport do I use to get out of the UK, and to get in to Morocco? And which passport to get back into the UK? Is it possible to use the Moroccan passport as a visa at check-in at departure in the UK?

Comment: We also have a [tag:dual-nationality] tag you could add if you think it's more important than one of the current tags. Five is the maximum number of tags allowed on a question.

Comment: fellas, thank you for the clarifications, i appreciate them

Answer (score 13):

**To exit the UK:**
Use the passport you used to enter the UK. They will probably want to put an exit stamp in your passport and will look for the corresponding entry stamp.

**To enter Morroco:**
Use your Morrocco passport.

**To exit Morocco:**

1. Use your Kenyan passport with the UK student Visa with the airlines
   to prove you're authorized to enter the UK.
2. Show your Morocco passport to Morrocan emigration.

**To reenter the UK:**
I'm not familiar with the details of student Visas, but I would use the Kenyan passport with the student Visa since I assume you're reentering on a student status.

*I would confirm all of this with the appropriate countries Consular sections before starting my trip.*

Comment: You should definitely use the Moroccan passport at Moroccan exit immigration, but you will need to show the Kenyan passport with visa at airline checkin.

Comment: My concern is that Kenyans need a visa to go to morocco and it might be something i will be asked, so when leaving the uk, do i show the morroccan passport like a visa?

Comment: Airlines usually ensure you meet the entry requirements before you leave, usually at the check-in counter. If you show them your Moroccan passport that should demonstrate that you're authorized to enter Morocco.

Just make sure at immigration you exit using the passport you entered on. You're probably also okay explaining your situation to the airline or immigration folks..... they've seen people with multiple passports before.

Comment: "To exit the UK" There are no exit checks in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Kenyan passport to exit and enter UK, provided the student visa allows this. Moroccan to enter and exit Morocco. This way you have all the required entry/exit stamps.